# Probability distribution based on rounded numbers

Tags: probability

I'm hoping someone can help me with an unconventional but probably simple question for you guys.  I apologize in advance if I get any terminology wrong, I'm not the best at math.

So suppose that 1000 people (although I don't think the actual number should matter) are surveyed each day, for five days about whether or not they are happy - everyone answers and there are only two possible answers: yes or no.  After each day, the percentage of people that day who said "yes" is tabulated and rounded to the nearest whole number.  What I would like to do is determine the likelihood of the overall week's percentage (also rounded to the nearest whole number) being a particular number, using only the daily rounded numbers.

So I realize that if the daily rounded numbers average out to exactly a whole number then the outcome is guaranteed i.e. if the 5 days were: 56, 56, 57, 58, 58, then the lowest possible actual numbers on each day would have been 55.5, 55.5, 56.5, 57.5, 57.5 and the highest possible numbers on each day would have been 56.499..., 56.499..., 57.499..., 58.499..., 58.499... - either way, the overall percentage for the week must be > 56.5 and <57.499... thus I know for a fact that it will be rounded to 57.  However if we take any set of 5 numbers that does not average out to a whole number, the outcome is uncertain.

For instance, take the daily numbers 61, 61, 61, 62, 63.  The average of course is 61.6.  Using the same method above (averaging the lowest and highest possible exact daily numbers that would generate these rounded numbers) I know that the actual overall percentage for the week must be > 61.1 and < 62.1.  Now if that entire range was equally likely, then it would simply be a 60% chance that the overall weeks number would be in the range that gets rounded up to 62.  But intuitively, I know that the probability should follow a normal distribution curve, and thus the chances of the actual number being between 61.5 and 62.1 must be > 60%, since that range encompasses more of the middle of the curve where the probabilities are higher.

And this is where I don't know where to go.  Ultimately I'm trying to get a distribution curve or equation that would tell me the overall probability of a particular outcome based on the daily rounded numbers.  If anyone could provide some insight, I would be very grateful.